# A class pointer does not name a type

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have 3 C++ files:

Main.cpp

```
#include "FileA.h"
```

FileA.h

```
#include "FileB.h" 

class FileA{

    private: 

        FileB* b; //It doesn't give error here!
};
```

FileB.h

```
class FileB{

    private:
        FileA* A; //The error is here!

};
```

When I run the Main.cpp file, the compiler says:

```
'FileA' does not name a type, did you mean 'FileB'?
```

This is the first time I use StackOverflow to ask question so it's kinda messy, sorry. Anyone knows how to fix this problem and the cause of it ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try arranging your files in reverse order (`FileB.h`, then `FileA.h`, then `Main.cpp`). That is the order in which the compiler sees their contents, and you might see the problem when they are displayed in that order.

Comment: [Where can I use a forward declaration, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent too much time commenting and not answering. This is pretty much what Bolov showed, but with more of the gory details.

Let's looks at this the way the compiler does. Whenever the compiler, [really the preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6264249/4581301), finds an `include` directive, it replaces the `include` with the content of the included file.

The compiler starts with Main.cpp. It sees the

```
#include "FileA.h"
```

and replaces it with FileA.h so now you have

```cpp
#include "FileB.h" 

class FileA{

    private: 

        FileB* b; //It doesn't give error here!
};
```

The compiler picks up where it left off and finds

```
#include "FileB.h"
```

and replaces it with FileB.h. Now you have

```cpp
class FileB{

    private:
        FileA* A; //The error is here!

};
class FileA{

    private: 

        FileB* b; //It doesn't give error here!
};
```

No more preprocessor work is required, so the compiler looks at the combined file. `FileB` is the first thing defined, and it needs a declaration of `FileA` to satisfy `FileA* A;`. The compiler hasn''t seen `FileA` yet, so it emits an error and keeps going. It finds `FileA` and the `FileB* b;` member, but at this point it's seen `FileB`, so no error.

When you have a pointer or reference it's enough for the compiler to know that the identifier exists, even if it doesn't know what the named type looks like, because it doesn't have to hold an instance of the type. The fix is to forward declare `FileA ahead of` FileB`

```cpp
class FileA; // forward declaration
class FileB{

    private:
        FileA* A; //The error is here!

};
class FileA{

    private: 

        FileB* b; //It doesn't give error here!
};
```

Now `FileA* A;` is satisfied that there is such a thing as a `FileA` It doesn't know enough to construct one or how to access anything inside a `FileA` yet, but no one has asked it to.

This resolves to a FileB.h that looks like

```cpp
class FileA; // forward declaration
class FileB{

    private:
        FileA* A; //The error is here!

};
```

Bolov makes a very good point about preventing multiple includes of the same file. Sometimes you can get away with it, but often you wind up with recursive loops and nigh-inscrutable error messages. Best to be avoided with your choice of [Include Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Now I know what the #include does. You save my project.

Answer (score 2):

`#include` preprocessor directive copies the content of the file. So the content of `Main.cpp` becomes the content `FileA.h` since that `#include` is the only expression in the file.

The file `FileA.h` starts by including `FileB.h` so the content of `Main.cpp` becomes:

`Main.cpp` preprocessor output:

```
class FileB{

    private:
        FileA* A; //The error is here!

};

class FileA{

    private: 

        FileB* b; //It doesn't give error here!
};
```

As you can see on the line with the eror `FileA` is not declared yet. Since both `FileA` and `FileB` need each other you need to foward delcare the classes before use in each header. And don't forget to guard against recursive includes. I use `#pragama once` because is simpler and supported on all major compilers, even if it is not standard:

Main.cpp

```
#include "FileA.h"
```

FileA.h

```
#pragma once
#include "FileB.h" 

class FileB;

class FileA{

    private: 

        FileB* b;
};
```

FileB.h

```
#pragma once
#include "FileA.h"

class FileA;

class FileB{

    private:
        FileA* A;

};
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried ur solution and it worked!. Too bad I can only mark one answer as the solution.